# Why all LDAP user passwords are incorrectly imported? And can't be modified?

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, slapd

First of all I am new to OpenLDAP setup. I have followed instructions coming from:

[HowToForge.com linux openldap setup](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_openldap_setup_server_client)

```
#root
dn: dc=localhost,dc=com
dc: localhost
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: rootObject
ou: localhost.com

dn: ou=People,dc=localhost,dc=com
ou: People
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: uid=root,ou=People,dc=localhost,dc=com
uid: root
cn: Manager
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword {crypt}$6$l4IzdQnUVegcZdxH$L3winJgau4xxFBcvXgg2dzLs0eQ.8LS9rKWx6DeV/JPNnCZW6i9oCS/9rCtAzrdCie3qrgSMYvz4zKhJXIwcL1
shadowLastChange: 15792
shadowMin: 0
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 0
gidNumber: 0
homeDirectory: /root
gecos: root

dn: uid=operator,ou=People,dc=localhost,dc=com
uid: operator
cn: operator
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword: {crypt}*
shadowLastChange: 15628
shadowMin: 0
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
loginShell: /sbin/nologin
uidNumber: 11
gidNumber: 0
homeDirectory: /root
gecos: operator

dn: uid=adam,ou=People,dc=localhost,dc=com
uid: adam
cn: adam
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword: {crypt}$6$oZVvz21C$HCHh90xQhCYN.9YCHG7P3d.y7Kx3Od6qkBjJy.S0QDSh57STBPJyHjxhuBbe73BB0QGFqj86JqnJCe3HqCJmD.
shadowLastChange: 15806
shadowMin: 0
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 502
gidNumber: 502
homeDirectory: /home/adam

dn: uid=eve,ou=People,dc=localhost,dc=com
uid: eve
cn: eve
......
```

When I imported all uses contained within this ldif file using command:

```
slapadd -n 2 -l /etc/openldap/localhost.com.ldif
```

I ran into NO errors.

Then I used JXplorer to confirm that all objects are there in thr LDAP tree, under localhost.com.

However when I try to authenticate against LDAP users, I always got the feedback from applications that user password is not correct? Why this?!

Is it because of the "hased/shadowed" passwd as defined in this ldif? Shall I use plain passwd instead?

Also I cannot modify the user passwords from within JXploprer GUI as it complains:

"unable to perform modify operation"...

I figured out that it must have something to do with my slapd.conf. Like I cannot modify user passwords. Is there a way to resolve this in slapd.conf?

```
#######################################################################
# database definitions
#######################################################################

database    bdb
suffix      "dc=localhost,dc=com"
checkpoint  1024 15
rootdn      "cn=Manager,dc=localhost,dc=com"
# Cleartext passwords, especially for the rootdn, should
# be avoided.  See slappasswd(8) and slapd.conf(5) for details.
# Use of strong authentication encouraged.
# rootpw        secret
# rootpw        {crypt}ijFYNcSNctBYg

rootpw {SSHA}ITG/tKlnULV84uCPuZRVUoSvKpqKTwjB

# The database directory MUST exist prior to running slapd AND 
# should only be accessible by the slapd and slap tools.
# Mode 700 recommended.
directory   /var/lib/ldap

# Indices to maintain for this database
index objectClass                       eq,pres
index ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname      eq,pres,sub
index uidNumber,gidNumber,loginShell    eq,pres
index uid,memberUid                     eq,pres,sub
index nisMapName,nisMapEntry            eq,pres,sub
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How are you hashing your password?

`userPassword {crypt}$6$l4IzdQnUVegcZdxH$L3winJgau4xxFBcvXgg2dzLs0eQ.8LS9rKWx6DeV/JPNnCZW6i9oCS/9rCtAzrdCie3qrgSMYvz4zKhJXIwcL1`

That looks like the hash is wrong. It should be a lot shorter. I ran into something that looks similar a while back, and fixed by adding a random salt to my crypt function.